# Ubuntu Battery Life on XPS 13 9343

Tags: 18.04, dell, power-management, battery, tlp

Running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on my Dell XPS 13 9343 (2015).

From my experience, Windows would get me around 5-6 hours comfortably, and in comparison Ubuntu seems to top out at 4-5. I've installed TLP already and  it seems to have been to its default settings, but I haven't seen any improvements in battery life.

Is it possible that I might've installed Ubuntu in a way that just consumes more battery (I checked/unchecked some BIOS Settings following the instructions when installing) or should I just continue tweaking it using more battery-saving tools (laptop-mode-tools & pm-utils, etc).

Disclaimer: I understand many XPS/Ubuntu posts have been made a while ago, but I'm mainly concerned about the possibility of an error during installation.

Comment: Linux distros usually [consume more battery than Windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119606/why-does-linux-have-poor-battery-life-by-default-compared-to-windows).

Comment: Recenty, some kernel improvements have led to a (somewhat?) better battery live. So from 18.10 onwards, we should get some improvements in battery life after a stock installation. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-417-power&num=1